# How to fire button click event from user contol in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a time on user control, and button on the web page. On perticular time I want to fire button click event. Please tell me how do this.

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Does it submit a form? I really do hope so because or else whatever code that is executed when button is clicked can be put to a function and can be called both by the button click event and other subsequent events that require it. If you want to submit a form i suggest you use Form.Submit

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Answer (score 2):

`.click` javascript method will help you.

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button clicked code to run after five seconds, for example, you would do the following.

```
setTimeout("document.getElementById(\"buttonId\").click();", 5000)
```

This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) has basic information about timing in JavaScript.

It would be helpful if you could tell us more about the particular time-related user control you are using.